# Trouble with global variable while list depth finding via recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have a recursion function with a global variable for checking list depth, it works correct until you start it double or more times because variable doesn't reset. I've **already seen** the simplest way, but can I repair **my** code for correct work or it's just piece of dead code? Oh, I really have troubles with recursion..

```
depth = 1
def list_depth(arr):
    global depth
    for element in arr:
        # print(type(element))
        if type(element) == list:
            depth += 1
            list_depth(element)
        else:
            continue
        return depth
    return depth

print(list_depth([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6], 5], 4], 3], 2], 1])) # => 6 correct
print(list_depth([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6], 5], 4], 3], 2], 1])) # => 11 wrong
```

Comment: It's a global variable: it's value doesn't get reset to 1 between the two top-level calls.

Comment: Recursion does not mix well with global variables.

Comment: I still don't understand:(

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: After the first call to `list_depth` (which involves a number of recursive calls to `list_depth`), the value of `depth` is 6, not 1. (You can see this simply by adding `print(depth)` between the two calls.)

Comment: Yeah,I know. And I try to fix it but I don't know how

Comment: The most trivial thing you can do is simply set `depth = 1` before every (non recursive) call.

Comment: But consider the recursive definition: the depth of a list is 1 plus the depth of its deepest sublist. (A list with no sublists can be defined to have a depth of 1.)

Comment: You are also incrementing `depth` *every* time you descend into a sublist. Your first one only works because no list has more than one sublist in it.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways you could go about it...
if you really want to keep your code as it is you'll have to reset `depth` before each call
like this:

```
print(list_depth([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6], 5], 4], 3], 2], 1]))
depth=1
print(list_depth([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6], 5], 4], 3], 2], 1]))
```

output:

```
6
6
```

but a better solution could be sending depth as one of the function arguments instead of declaring it as a global argument

this should do the trick :

```
def list_depth(arr,depth=1):
    for element in arr:
        # print(type(element))
        if type(element) == list:
            depth += 1
            return list_depth(element,depth)
        else:
            continue
    return depth

print(list_depth([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6], 5], 4], 3], 2], 1])) 
print(list_depth([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6], 5], 4], 3], 2], 1]))
```

output:

```
6
6
```

Comment: thx, but this still doesn't work with it.. What have I done wrong?..
Log
[[77], 77, [[77]]]
<class 'list'>
[77]
<class 'int'>
2 should equal 3